# maximum recursion depth error?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

So I'm really new to this (3 days) and I'm on code academy, I've written this code for one of the activities but when I run it it displays maximum recursion depth error, I'm running it in the python console of code academy and simultaneously on my own ipython console. The hint on the page is not helpful, can anybody explain how to fix this?
Thanks

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return (nights * 140)

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if plane_ride_cost("Charlotte"):
        return (183)
    if plane_ride_cost("Tampa"):
        return (220)
    if plane_ride_cost("Pittsburgh"):
        return (222)
    if plane_ride_cost("Loas Angeles"):
        return (475)

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost    

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return hotel_cost(nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Comment: *edit* I am aware of the spelling mistake :')

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe:**

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return (183)
    if city == "Tampa":
        return (220)
    if city == "Pittsburgh":
        return (222)
    if city == "Los Angeles":
        return (475)
```

**The error was:**

The `plane_ride_cost(city)` called `plane_ride_cost("Charlotte")` in every recursion step.

**Not the best, but a better approach:**

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

plane_cost = {
    'Charlotte' : 183,
    'Tampa' : 220,
    'Pittsburgh' : 222,
    'Los Angeles' : 475,
}

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city not in plane_cost:
        raise Exception('City "%s" not registered.' % city)
    else:
        return plane_cost[city]

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost    

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return hotel_cost(nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Comment: better use a `dict`, raise an `Exception` if `city` not in the dict.